# Optimal radiating $(d{-}1)$-flats within a sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, applications

Permit me to revisit an earlier unresolved MO question,
"[Chord arrangement that avoids confining small or large disks](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76980/6094)"
with a (very!) specific version, inspired by radiation therapy.
The main idea is to minimize the size of tumor (a ball) that could be missed
by radiation probes.
More specifically,

> Let $S$ be a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
>   You are permitted to slice through $S$ with $n=d{+}1$ planes (of radiation),
>   each $(d{-}1)$-dimensional flats.
>   Is it the case that, in order to minimize the size of any missed(unradiated) ball
>   within $S$,
>   one should arrange the flats to determine
>   a regular simplex, whose insphere has radius $r = \frac{1}{3}$?

[image: TriTetraSph]
I feel this should be a theorem for $n=d{+}1$ but (perhaps!)
very difficult to fathom for $n>d{+}1$.

Comment: No.  I think cake slicing strategies reduce it to a two dimensional problem.

Comment: Of course, if you say ellipsoid instead of ball, then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by The Masked Avenger, this is certainly false for large $n$: using regularly spaced parallel planes one hits all spheres of radius larger than $1/n$. Note that this kind of strategy also works inside an ellipsoid, or any shape.

Comment: Agreed. However a different idea is needed if the tumors are not balls but just convex.